# trigger looping by sqlite

Tags: sqlite, loops, triggers

i have created a table name profitLoss (has attribute month,debit,credit,profit,status) and want to use trigger to perform profit and status. my trigger cannot be created after i inserted looping.

this is my trigger code:

```
CREATE    TRIGGER    [PROFIT]
AFTER    UPDATE    OF    [credit]
ON    [profitLoss]
BEGIN
UPDATE    profitLoss    SET    profitLoss    = 
cast   (
         (
                  (profitLoss.debit)   -   (profitLoss.credit)
         )    AS    INT
      )  ;

    when    profitLoss.profit < 0    begin
    UPDATE    profitLoss    SET    status    =    'LOSS'  ;

    when    profitLoss.profit > 0    begin
    UPDATE    profitLoss    SET    status    =    'PROFIT'  ;
END;
```

it gives result:

```
near "when": syntax error:
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use WHEN inside the trigger body (see the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)).
In this case, you can use a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) to select between different values.

Furthermore, an UPDATE statement without a WHERE clause will update *all* rows in the table.
You have to search for the row that caused the trigger to run, usually with some ID:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PROFIT
AFTER UPDATE OF credit ON profitLoss
BEGIN
    UPDATE profitLoss
    SET profitLoss = CAST(debit - credit AS INT),
        status     = CASE
                       WHEN profit < 0 THEN 'LOSS'
                       WHEN profit > 0 THEN 'PROFIT'
                       ELSE                 status
                     END
    WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
END;
```